# Theorem about two real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

My question is:
$a,b$ are two positive real numbers such that their product is constant,equal to $k$ say. Prove: the sum $a+b$ is minimum if and only if $a = b= \sqrt k$.

Can this be solved using $A.M.-\;G.M.$ inequality? If yes,then I would like to know it that way too.

Answer (score 15):

We have 
$$(a+b)^2=(a-b)^2+4ab=(a-b)^2+4k.$$
To minimize $a+b$, we minimize $(a+b)^2$. To do this, we minimize $(a-b)^2$, by setting $a=b$.

Comment: I like this answer better :)

Comment: @TheChaz: The two answers complement each other.

Comment: André, could you drop by the chat?

Comment: Yes, this one's more elegant.

Comment: Hey André Nicolas:I did not get it. Please will you explain this to me ?

Comment: @meg_1997: Since $a+b$ must be positive, we minimize $a+b$ precisely if we minimize $(a+b)^2$. But $(a+b)^2=(a-b)^2+4k$. Since $k$ is fixed, the right-hand side is minimized by making $(a-b)^2$ as small as possible. But $(a-b)^2\ge 0$ always, so it is a minimum when it is $0$, that is, when $a=b$. Since $ab=k^2$, putting $a=b$ we get $b^2=a^2=k$, so $b=a=\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: I'm there now. Chrome seems to be crashing now and then so I might appear and dissapear.

Comment: sorry but i have a doubt , in the last sentence should ab be equal to 'k' instead of k square?

Comment: @meg_1997: Yes, sorry, typo. That's the problem with comments!

Comment: @ André Nicolas :i got this solution well but can we solve it by A.M. G.M. inequality too?

Comment: @meg_1997 What André has written is nothing but the proof of AM-GM for two real numbers $a$ and $b$ and argued out why equality in AM-GM occurs when $a=b$. To rewrite André identity in AM-GM form, divide André equation by $4$ to get that $$\left( \dfrac{a+b}2\right) = \sqrt{ab + \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)^2}$$ and since $\left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)^2 \geq 0$, we get that $$\left( \dfrac{a+b}2\right) \geq \sqrt{ab}$$ with equality holding when $\left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)^2 = 0$ i.e. when $a=b$.

Comment: @ Marvis: Thanks for that

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked specifically for a proof using the A.M.-G.M. inequality, I'll provide one, even though it's not as elegant or direct as the proof in [André Nicolas's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155369) (which does not use the A.M.-G.M. inequality).

By the A.M.-G.M. inequality, $\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}2$,

i.e. $2\sqrt{ab}\le a+b$, with equality iff $a=b$.

Since the left-hand side of that inequality is fixed ($2\sqrt k$), we have that the right-hand side is equal to a fixed number it is not less than — i.e. is minimized — iff $a=b$, as sought.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ab = k \Rightarrow b = k/a$
Then to minimize $S = a + b = a + k/a$, take derivatives.

Comment: Just as long as I don't get more than five downvotes for each upvote, I'll be in the black :)

Answer (score 1):

Let us rephrase the problem: find the minimum of $\,x+y\,$ when $$x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+\,\,,\,\,and\,\,xy=k=constant$$

We already get that $\,\displaystyle{y=\frac{k}{x}}\,$ , so we need the minimum of the function$$f(x)=x+y=x+\frac{k}{x}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=1-\frac{k}{x^2}=0\Longleftrightarrow x=\pm|k|$$

Well, check with the derivative's changes of signs or with the second derivative test which one is what.